# Unable to Run container ( Path error for executable )

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, virtualenv

**DockerFile**

```
FROM python:3.12.0a6-bullseye

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get -y autoremove

RUN apt install python3 -y \
    && apt install python3-pip -y \
    && apt install python3-venv -y 

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV PATH="$PATH:/app/venv/bin/python3"

RUN echo $PATH


RUN pip install virtualenv

RUN pip install cmake

RUN virtualenv venv

RUN venv/bin/pip install -r latestreq.txt

EXPOSE 8001

RUN chmod +x venv/bin/python3

CMD [ "venv/bin/python3","manage.py","runserver"]
```

**Error i am getting**

> ```
> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start
> ```
>
> container process: exec: "photoframe-container": executable file not
> found in $PATH: unknown.
> ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:

Comment: The `python` image already comes with Python and Pip preinstalled, and the standard library includes the `venv` module now; you do not need the `apt-get` lines at all.  Does relying on the version of Python in the base image help things at all?  You also can probably get away without a virtual environment (the Docker image itself is an isolated Python library installation) which can also simplify things.

Comment: so far it gives me error in both the cases, even using python3 stand alone gives executable path error